# Complex Jquery Selector With Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a demo of a lotto site where a user is presented with one section full of the balls and a second section that will fill up with his/her selections.

What I am trying to do is create a jQuery function that will run when a user clicks on a ball, this function must retrieve the number of the ball that was clicked as well as the color of the ball (background-image) and then set the number and the background-image to the next available ball.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8kq5p6gb/1/

This is my jQuery function, it stores the number and background of the clicked ball and then tries to find the next available ball open and applies that text and background to it but it currently does not work.
 When I click on a ball I get this **error** :

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] a:nth-child(1)
```

**For Code :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var line_counter = 1;
    var number_counter = 1;

    $('.draw-selection-wrapper.choice .draw-number').click(function (e) {
        event.preventDefault(e);

        var number = $(this).text(); ;
        var background = $(this).css('background-image');

        var row = $('.draw-selection-wrapper.selections div:nth-child(' + line_counter + ')');

        var link = $(row + ' a:nth-child(' + number_counter + ')');

        link.text(number);
        link.css('background-image', background);

        number_counter = number_counter + 1;
        if (number_counter == 8) {
            line_counter = line_counter + 1;
            number_counter = 1;
        }

    });


});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="draw-numbers-outer-wrapper">
                        <div class="draw-selection-wrapper choice">
                            <div class="draw-number-row one">
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">1</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">2</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">3</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">4</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">5</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">6</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">7</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="draw-number-row two">
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">8</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">9</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">10</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">11</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">12</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">13</a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number">14</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="draw-selection-wrapper selections">
                            <div class="draw-number-row">
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="draw-number-row">
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                                <a href="" class="draw-number"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.draw-selection-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.draw-number-row {
    height: 36px;
    border: 1px solid #C6C4C5;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.line-number {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12px;
}
.draw-number {
    width: 9%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin: 0px 2.5% 0px 2.5%;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
}
.draw-selection-wrapper.selections .draw-number {
    margin: 0px 2% 0px 2%;
}
.draw-number-row.one .draw-number {
    background-color: red;
}
.draw-number-row.two .draw-number {
    background-color: teal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is a jQuery object, not a string, and as such you end up with `[Object, object]` when you try to concantenate the object into a string.

You could use the context selector instead

```
var row = $('.draw-selection-wrapper.selections div:nth-child(' + line_counter + ')');

var link = $('a:nth-child(' + number_counter + ')', row);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8kq5p6gb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = row.find('a:nth-child(' + number_counter + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8kq5p6gb/3/)

replace this

```
var row = $('.draw-selection-wrapper.selections div:nth-child(' + line_counter + ')');
var link = $(row + ' a:nth-child(' + number_counter + ')');
```

by

```
var row = '.draw-selection-wrapper.selections div:nth-child(' + line_counter + ')';
        var link = $(row + ' a:nth-child(' + number_counter + ')');
```